# How do I rebase a chain of local git branches?

Tags: git, rebase

Suppose I have a chain of local git branches, like this:

```
       master    branch1   branch2
          |         |         |
o----o----o----A----B----C----D
```

I pull in an upstream change onto the master branch:

```
              branch1   branch2
                 |         |
            A----B----C----D
           /
o----o----o----o
               |
            master
```

Now I rebase branch1, giving me this:

```
                        branch2
                           |
            A----B----C----D
           /          
o----o----o----o----A'---B'
               |         |
            master    branch1
```

Note that because of rebasing branch1, commits A and B have been rewritten as A' and B'.

Here's my problem: now I want to rebase branch2. The obvious syntax is `git rebase branch1 branch2`, but that definitely does not work. What I want it to do is just reapply C and D on top of branch1, but instead it tries to reconcile A and A' and it considers them conflicting.

This does work:

```
git rebase --onto branch1 branch2^^ branch2
```

This assumes I know that branch2 has exactly 2 commits beyond the previous branch1 ref.

Since `git rebase --onto` works, is there a 1-line git command that will rebase branch2 on top of a newly-rebased branch1, in a way that I don't have to know exactly how many commits were part of branch2? (I want to specify some magic ref instead of branch2^^ for the middle argument.)

Or is there some other approach I'm overlooking?

I would be most interested in a solution that scales well to extreme cases, not just two branches - suppose I've got something more like 5 local branches, all chained on one another, and I want to rebase all of them together.

Comment: Did you have conflicts when you rebased `branch1` on top of `master`? In a general case, `git rebase branch1 branch2` would work as expected, but in certain cases it might not, for example if you had to resolve conflicts when rebasing `branch1` on top of `master`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

2022: I described last August in "[Git interactive rebase: how to move other branches (refs) automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73429249/6309)" a [new rebase option `--update-refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---update-refs) (Git 2.38, Q3 2022):

> Automatically force-update any branches that point to commits that are being rebased.
> Any branches that are checked out in a worktree are not updated in this way.

```
              branch1   branch2
                 |         |
            A----B----C----D
           /
o----o----o----o
               |
             main
```

```
git switch branch2
git rebase --update-refs main
```

```
                    branch1     branch2
                       |           |
                 A'----B'----C'----D'
                /
o----o----o----o
               |
             main
```

---

2013: One-line:

```
git rebase --onto branch1 branch1tmp branch2
```

That supposes to make a `branch1tmp` on `branch1` *before* rebasing `branch1`.

```
git checkout branch1
git branch branch1tmp
git rebase master
git rebase --onto branch1 branch1tmp branch2
```

---

That being said, check what `ORIG_HEAD` references.
From [git rebase man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> `ORIG_HEAD` is set to point at the tip of the branch before the reset.

So check if this would work (and scale better):

```
git checkout branch1
git rebase master
git rebase --onto branch1 ORIG_HEAD branch2
git rebase --onto branch2 ORIG_HEAD branch3
...
```

Comment: Thanks! ORIG_HEAD looks by far like the most natural way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

```bash
git rebase master branch1
git rebase --onto HEAD ORIG_HEAD branch2
git rebase --onto HEAD ORIG_HEAD branch3
# ...
git rebase --onto HEAD ORIG_HEAD branchN
```

I have a git alias script to do this:

```bash
rebase-chain = "!f() { \
  for i in ${@}; do \
    git rebase --onto HEAD ORIG_HEAD $i; \
  done; \
}; f"
```

which can make the workflow like:

```bash
git rebase master branch1 # start with a normal rebase
git rebase-chain branch2 branch3 branch4 ... branchN
```

**bonus**

assuming you have `bash-completion` for `git`:

```bash
__git_complete "git rebase-chain" _git_branch
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is a subset of [Modify base branch and rebase all children at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181045/modify-base-branch-and-rebase-all-children-at-once/58864618#58864618)

I recently started using [git-chain](https://github.com/Shopify/git-chain) which is a tool to solve this problem.

Basically you specify a chain

```
git chain setup -c myfeature master branch1 branch2
```

Once this chain is set up, you can pull in commits from `master`, then you can run `git chain rebase -c myfeature` and the tool figures out all the refs and rebases everything nicely for you.

As an added benefit, it also calculates and handles any amendments or new commits to `branch1` and `branch2`.

Answer (score 1):

The git-branchless suite of tools can neatly solve this problem:

```
$ git move -s A -d master
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

This will rebase `A`, as well as all of its descendants, and any branches pointing to any of those commits. See the [documentation for `git move`](https://github.com/arxanas/git-branchless/wiki/Command:-git-move).

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.38 has a new flag `--update-refs` to solve this exact problem. In your example:

```
git rebase --update-refs master
```

Example:

```
$ git checkout branch2
$ git log --decorate --all --oneline --graph
* 5b08e54 (master) 4
* 6790fdc 3
| * ee84471 (HEAD -> branch2) branch commit 4
| * 9da7c93 branch commit 3
| * c250fc6 (branch1) branch commit 2
| * bd5f222 branch commit 1
|/
* 2ec36a0 2
* ecce5ff 1
* 8bb07ae (tag: root) root
$ git rebase --update-refs master
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/branch2.
Updated the following refs with --update-refs:
    refs/heads/branch1
$ git log --decorate --all --oneline --graph
* b37f0c7 (HEAD -> branch2) branch commit 4
* c20fc6f branch commit 3
* a231606 (branch1) branch commit 2
* 0e81768 branch commit 1
* 5b08e54 (master) 4
* 6790fdc 3
* 2ec36a0 2
* ecce5ff 1
* 8bb07ae (tag: root) root
```

Notice: I only rebased the "last" branch in the chain (branch2) onto the new base (master), and the in-between branches (branch1) got moved along automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What I would have loved is for `git checkout branch2 ; git rebase -i master` to show me `branch1` directly in the editor, and then when I save the editor, that the branch1 got updated accordingly.  So I could move a commit from branch2 to branch1 directly in `git rebase -i` and have that "stick". Maybe with a '--rebase-branches' or something.

So arrhhh, I share your pain.

What I do is somwhat of a hack that mimics this missing feature. I often find that during creating long-lived branches, I keep accumulating stuff that should've gone into master before "this" branch. Fixing coding standard breaches, discovering and fixing obvious errors, documentation updates for existing code, etc. This is what I'd use your `branch1` for. And then the commits that actually are part of my new feature go in `branch2`.

So what I do instead of creating a `branch1` branch is to create a `branch1` pseudo-branch "marker" - a tiny commit that I'll throw away later with `git rebase`. I create it like:

```
touch marker.master
git add marker.branch1
git commit -m "*** BRANCH1 ***" marker.branch1
```

Now when I create commits, I mix commits that should go into master before this branch and "new" commits for this actual branch.

When it becomes time to clean up / rebase, I `git rebase -i master`. Now my `*** BRANCH1 ***` commit is obvious in the list of commits, and I can move commits destined for `branch1` up above that "line".

Because I don't have an actual `branch1` branch, `git rebase master` does exactly what I want, it moves `branch2` and my `branch1` pseudo-branch marker as one unit.

When I'm done rebasing and am ready to push, I manually make a note of the commit ID for `*** BRANCH1 ***`, say `abcdef1`, and then:

```
git checkout -b branch1 abcdef1^
```

Then:

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase -i branch1
```

And remove the `abcdef1` commit.

This way I can easily move commits between my `branch1` and `branch2` branches during `git rebase -i` and only actually create a real git `branch1` branch  at the very end.

But oh, I'd really like for `git rebase -i` to do this for me!