# Modify base branch and rebase all children at once

Tags: git

I have something like this:

```
A //branch 1
 \
  B - C //branch 2
       \
        D //branch 3
```

And I would like to get something like this:

```
 A - E //branch_1
      \
       B' - C' //branch_2
             \
              D' //branch_3
```

I would like to perform a command and rebase all branches at once, so I don't have to rebase them one by one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: no, it's not possible ... but you *can* minimize the amount of work you have to do.  Long answer on minimizing work follows.

The key to understanding this is that Git's branch *names*—the names `branch_1`, `branch_2`, and `branch_3` in your example—are merely identifiers that "point to" one specific commit.  It's the commits themselves that form the actual branches.  For details, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  Meanwhile, what `git rebase` does is to *copy* some commits, with the new copies normally being made on a new base (hence "re-base").

In your particular case, there's only one *chain of commits* that requires copying.  That's the `B--C--D` chain.  If we strip off all the labels (branch names) we can draw the graph fragment this way:

```
A--E
 \
  B--C--D
```

Your task is to copy `B--C--D` to `B'--C'--D'`, which are like `B` through `D` but come after `E` instead of coming after `A`.  I'll put them on top so that we can keep the original `B--C--D` chain in the picture too:

```
     B'-C'-D'
    /
A--E
 \
  B--C--D
```

Once you've made the copies, you can then change the *labels* so that they point to the copies, rather than pointing to the originals; and now we need to move `D'` up so that we can point `branch_2` to `C'`:

```
          D'   <-- branch_3
         /
     B'-C'     <-- branch_2
    /
A--E           <-- branch_1
```

This takes a minimum of two Git commands to accomplish:

1. `git rebase`, to copy `B-C-D` to `B'-C'-D'` and move `branch_3` to point to `D'`.  Normally this would be two commands:

   ```
   git checkout branch_3 && git rebase branch_1
   ```

   but you can actually do this with one Git command as `git rebase` has the option of doing the initial `git checkout`:

   ```
   git rebase branch_1 branch_3
   ```
2. `git branch -f`, to re-point `branch_2`.

   We know (from our careful graph drawing that showed us that we could do a single `git rebase` of `branch_3` to copy all the commits) that `branch_2` points to the commit "one step back" from the commit to which `branch_3` points.  That is, at the start, `branch_2` names commit `C` and `branch_3` names commit `D`.  Hence, once we're all done, `branch_2` needs to name commit `C'`.

   Since it *was* one step back from the tip of the old `branch_3`, it must be one step back from the tip of the new `branch_3` afterward.<sup>1</sup>  So now that we have done the `rebase` and have the `B'-C'-D'` chain, we simply direct Git to move the label `branch_2` to point one step back from wherever `branch_3` points:

   ```
   git branch -f branch_2 branch_3~1
   ```

Thus, for this case, it takes at least two Git commands (three if you prefer a separate `git checkout`).

Note that there are cases where more or different commands are required, even if we are moving / copying just two branch names.  For instance, if we started with:

```
F--J        <-- br1
 \
  G--H--K   <-- br2
      \
       I    <-- br3
```

and wanted to copy all of `G-H-(K;I)`, we cannot do this with one `git rebase` command.  What we *can* do is rebase either `br2` or `br3` first, copying three of the four commits; then use `git rebase --onto <target> <upstream> <branch>` with the remaining branch, to copy the one remaining commit.

(In fact, though, `git rebase --onto` is the most general form: we can always do the entire job with just a series of `git rebase --onto <target> <upstream> <branch>` commands, one per branch.  This is because `git rebase` really does *two* things: (1) copy some set of commits, possibly empty; (2) move a branch label a la `git branch -f`.  The copied set is determined from the result of `<upstream>..HEAD`—see [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) and footnote 1 below—and with the copy location being set by `--onto`; and the branch's destination is wherever `HEAD` winds up after doing the copying.  If the to-copy set is empty, `HEAD` winds up right at the `--onto` target.  So it *seems* like a simple(ish) script could do all the work ... but see footnote 1.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This assumes, however, that `git rebase` actually winds up copying *all* the commits.  (The safety level of this assumption varies a lot depending on the rebase in question.)

In fact, while the initial set of commits to copy is determined by running `git rev-list --no-merges <upstream>..HEAD`—or its equivalent, really—that initial set is immediately further whittled-down by computing the `git patch-id` for each commit in both the "to copy" and "don't need to copy because now will be upstream" ranges.  That is, instead of `<upstream>..HEAD`, the rebase code uses `<upstream>...HEAD` combined with `--right-only --cherry-pick`.<sup>2</sup>  So we omit not just merge commits, but also commits that are already upstream.

We could write a script that does this ourselves, so that we can locate the relative position of each branch-name in the set of branches we wish to rebase.  (I did most of this as an experiment some time ago.)  But there is another problem: during the cherry-picking process, it's possible that some commits will become empty due to conflict resolution, and you will `git rebase --skip` them.  This *changes* the relative position of the remaining copied commits.

What this means in the end is that unless `git rebase` is augmented a bit, to record which commits map to which new commits and which commits were dropped entirely, it's impossible to make a completely-correct, completely-reliable multi-rebase script.  I think one could get sufficiently close, without modifying Git itself, using the `HEAD` reflog: this would only go awry if someone starts this kind of complex rebase, but then in the middle of it, does some `git reset --soft`s and the like and then resumes the rebase.

<sup>2</sup>This is literally true for some forms of `git rebase` and not for others.  The code to generate the list varies depends on whether you're using `--interactive` and/or `--keep-empty` and/or `--preserve-merges`.  A [non-interactive `git am` based rebase](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-rebase--am.sh) uses:

```
if test -n "$keep_empty"
then
    # we have to do this the hard way.  git format-patch completely squashes
    # empty commits and even if it didn't the format doesn't really lend
    # itself well to recording empty patches.  fortunately, cherry-pick
    # makes this easy
    git cherry-pick ${gpg_sign_opt:+"$gpg_sign_opt"} --allow-empty \
        --right-only "$revisions" \
        ${restrict_revision+^$restrict_revision}
    ret=$?
else
    rm -f "$GIT_DIR/rebased-patches"

    git format-patch -k --stdout --full-index --cherry-pick --right-only \
        --src-prefix=a/ --dst-prefix=b/ --no-renames --no-cover-letter \
        "$revisions" ${restrict_revision+^$restrict_revision} \
        >"$GIT_DIR/rebased-patches"
    ret=$?

[snip]

    git am $git_am_opt --rebasing --resolvemsg="$resolvemsg" \
        ${gpg_sign_opt:+"$gpg_sign_opt"} <"$GIT_DIR/rebased-patches"
    ret=$?

[snip]
```

The `--cherry-pick --right-only` are passed through whichever command is used (cherry-pick or format-patch) to the `git rev-list` code, so that it can get the right-hand-side list of commit IDs, with "pre-picked cherries" removed, from the symmetric difference.

Interactive rebase is considerably more complicated (!).

Comment: To clarify: Is the script you included at the end part of the experiment you mention, or is it taken from the Git sources? (If so, it would be nice to mention/link them.)

Comment: @mkrieger1: the script fragment at the end is right out of `git-rebase--am.sh`. I will add a link. Tjanks for ptyo ixfes. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This question is a superset of [How do I rebase a chain of local git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834648/how-do-i-rebase-a-chain-of-local-git-branches/58864534#58864534)

The solution I am using today is a tool called [git-chain](https://github.com/Shopify/git-chain) which aims to solve this problem.

In your example, you can specify a chain

```
git chain setup -c myfeature branch1 branch2 branch3
```

Once this chain is set up, you can make new commits to `branch1` and then run `git chain rebase -c myfeature` and the tool figures out all the refs and rebases everything nicely for you.

As an added benefit, it also calculates and handles any amendments or new commits to `branch1`, `branch2`, and `branch3`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to at least find out *which branches* you will have to update after the initial rebase, you can run

```
$ git branch --contains <commit A>
```

Answer (score 0):

The git-branchless suite of tools can neatly solve this problem:

```
$ git checkout branch1
$ git commit -m 'E'

$ git move -s B -d branch1

# the above is the same as the following,
# because `branch1` is already checked out:
$ git move -s B

# or, if you want to address branches instead of commits
# (this will also move all descendant commits/branches):
$ git move -b branch2 -d branch1
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

See the [documentation for `git move`](https://github.com/arxanas/git-branchless/wiki/Command:-git-move).