# How to 'git pull --rebase' for all Git branches?

Tags: git, github, version-control, rebase, git-pull

**How to 'git pull --rebase' for all Git branches?**

I need to make git bundle frequently with latest source hence, I run `git pull --rebase` for each branch manually. When I run `git pull --rebase --all` I see for current active branch rebased is done but for other branch I see "head is some # commit ahead" this type of message. Is there any git tool running which will result like running `git pull --rebase` after switching each branch manually?

Comment: As a general rule, the `--all` option is not useful. If you're a Git expert, `--all` can sometimes be useful—but not in this case. (There are different Git commands with different `--all` meanings, but for `git pull`, `--all` is passed to `git fetch`, and for `git fetch`, only Git experts can understand what `--all` means and it's not useful in your, or most other, cases.)

Answer (score 2):

One, you would need to script that, as it is not supported by Git natively.

Two, as documented in "[Modify base branch and rebase all children at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42181820/6309)", you would need to deal with:

- children branches (branch of branch), which is not trivial,
- merge commits, even though [`git rebase --rebase-merges`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309) helps.