# Move all branch labels during git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

Suppose I have something like this, with branches `foo` and `bar`.

```
* e4417814 (HEAD -> master) A
* 91a3e3d2 B
| * afde3756 (foo) C
| * 6013afc7 D
| * eb9e3403 (bar) E
| * e098075d F
| * 577c0471 G
|/  
* f15d83fc H
* 5e06f896 I
```

If I do this:

```
git checkout foo
git rebase master
```

It will rebase `foo` onto `master` but leave `bar` behind. Something like this:

```
* 92eba834 (HEAD -> foo) C
* 938eb379 D
* be8377ab E
* 2bbe45b4 F
* 90aa0125 G
* e4417814 (master) A
* 91a3e3d2 B
| * eb9e3403 (bar) E
| * e098075d F
| * 577c0471 G
|/  
* f15d83fc H
* 5e06f896 I
```

I have to do something annoying like this to fix it.

```
git branch -f bar be8377ab
```

Is there any way to tell git to update any other branch labels too when it rebases?

Comment: Sadly, no, there's no built in mechanism to do this. :-(  I've often wished for this too, but there are some issues, the biggest one being that commits may not re-apply cleanly and you need to fix conflicts.

Comment: @phd: Not the same. That is two independent branches. This is one branch on top of another.

Comment: The situation is almost the same (I'm sure it's a dup) and the answer is the same: no way.

Comment: The situation is close but not the same. The answers in that question (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8508802/265521)) will not work in this situation. Please don't mark questions as duplicates if you aren't sure. It's really annoying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I rebase a chain of local git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834648/how-do-i-rebase-a-chain-of-local-git-branches)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rebase a chain of local git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834648/how-do-i-rebase-a-chain-of-local-git-branches)