# pushing stacked git branches back into main

Tags: git, gitlab

I've been trying to learn how to successfully create branch B off branch A, where both branches are local branches to me, and merge them into my company's code in GitLab. I've encountered a lot of interesting reading, but I'm still confused about how to best apply my branches back to main.

Right now we have:

```
main ->
  branch_A ->
    branch_B
```

Say that I finish branch A and merge my MR. At this point `main` will have the code from `branch A` (as a merge commit I believe), and `branch B` will have the code from `branch A` as the original commits.

I'm confused about how to finish my `branch B` MR, because I think there will be conflicts due to the `branch A` code being in both places. How can I get my `branch B` commits into `main` as well? This is on GitLab.

(If I try to rebase `branch B` onto `main` at this point, I think I would still see the same conflicts, but I would simply encounter them as part of the rebase. My goal is to somehow get my code into `main` without seeing a bunch of bogus conflicts.)

(For a while I thought that [this excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834648/how-do-i-rebase-a-chain-of-local-git-branches/20836211#20836211) would help me. However that is more about how to get changes from `main` into chained branches. My question is basically the reverse, how to get the code from the branches back into main as part of my MRs when I'm done. If I had followed that other question's instructions I guess that both MRs could be fast-forwarded. However I think that GitLab may not do a fast-forward.)

Comment: Rebase the part of B that doesn't include A onto main. Or do nothing, because the MR will not include the commits from A anyway. But personally if I haven't pushed B I like to rebase.

Comment: Why won’t the MR include the commits from A, since they are also part of the branch? Or in your alternative, how do I only rebase “the part of B that doesn’t include A” onto main?

Comment: 1. Because they are now part of main. — 2. Using `rebase --onto main branchA branchB`.

Comment: @matt is right, merging branch B into main will only merge/commit the changes that were not already on branch A (and by then on master, since a merge from A to main was already performed).
You could even do a simple test: open a repo with two branches that are equal, commit the same change on both branches. Merge. The merge will not commit changes (diff is empty).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tl;dr: After having merged branch A, you merge branch B. Done.

You started with this history:

```
--o--o                 <-- main
      \
       o--o--o         <-- branch A
              \
               o--o    <-- branch B
```

Then you merged branch A. Assuming that Gitlab does not do fast-forward merges, you got this history:

```
--o--o---------MA      <-- main
      \       /
       o--o--o         <-- branch A
              \
               o--o    <-- branch B
```

At this point, the most natural thing to do is to merge branch B. Now you get this history:

```
--o--o---------MA-----MB  <-- main
      \       /      /
       o--o--o      /     <-- branch A
              \    /
               o--o       <-- branch B
```

In this merge, the commits on branch A will not cause any conflicts. The power of the commit graph is at work here: A three-way merge of commit `MA` and branch B is performed. The merge base is the tip of branch A. But since there is no content difference between the merge base (branch A) and `MA`, no conflicts can occur.

Others have suggested that you rebase branch B onto main instead. You can do that if you wish:

```
git rebase main branch_B
```

You get this history:

```
--o--o---------MA        <-- main
      \       / \
       o--o--o   \       <-- branch A
                  \
                   o--o  <-- branch B
```

During this operation, the commits on branch A will not cause any conflicts, either.

Now you can merge the rebased branch into main as well:

```
--o--o---------MA---------MB  <-- main
      \       / \        /
       o--o--o   \      /     <-- branch A
                  \    /
                   o--o       <-- branch B
```

It is a matter of personal taste or of convention how your team operates whether you rebase branch B or not. It is absolutely not necessary to do so.

Comment: What if branch A is merged into main branch in `Rebasing and merging` manner(fast-forward merge)? will it make any differences?

Comment: @hide1nbush If A was fast-forwarded (which implies that it was *not* rebased) into main, then B can be fast-forwarded as well. However, if A was rebased, then it would make sense to rebase B as well. Whether this would cause any mishaps depends on whether rebasing A went smoothly or caused conflicts.

Comment: If you `rebase` and `merge` A first, the B branch becomes detached because its `merge-base` is gone. If you want to rebase you must merge B into A and then rebase to main.

Comment: This seems like good answer, though a couple improvements might make it even better: 

1) elaborate on "In this merge, the commits on branch A will not cause any conflicts. The power of the commit graph is at work here." 

I think what you're alluding to is that ultimately it's just performing a 3-way merge, and since the commits from Branch A will be in both locations they won't be detected as diffs in the merge. Is that right?

2) For the case where "you rebase branch B onto main instead", could you provide the command for that? Do we need a flag to exclude the A commits from replay?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have incorporated them. You do not need any special flags for the rebase command to exclude commits of branch A.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Branch A was merged to main, you should merge main into Branch B, or rebase Branch B with main's modifications. After that, fix the merge conflicts that might appear before developing anything else on Branch B.

Some companies prefer merging, others prefer rebasing, and these have implications on the git history, so talk to your team leader before choosing to one or the other.

One last thing I want to point out (given the diagram you drew) is that I have a feeling you believe there is a hierarchy between branches: B is child of A that is a child of main. *That is not the case.* Branches don't "own" other branches, as the image of a "tree" would lead you to think. They're more like lanes on a highway:

```
=======================    
main
-----------------------
Branch A
-----------------------
Branch B
=======================
```

You can switch (merge/rebase) and purpose those lanes however you like, they are completely separate entities. What binds them in a hierarchy is a social contract between you, your team, and Gitlab. Perhaps knowing this concept will clear more doubts you'll have in the future than if I explained only the issue you have now.

Comment: When I rebase `branch B` onto `main`, won't the rebase have a ton of bogus conflicts? Say I changed 500 lines in `branch A`, then I created `branch B` off it and changed 100 different lines. When I rebase `branch B` onto `main`, won't I get a lot of conflicts as it replays the 500 changed lines from the `branch A` commits onto `main`, which also has those changed lines?

Comment: On rebasing, you checkout into `Branch B` and then you run `git rebase main`. What that will do is it will find the last common ancestor between the two branches and replay every change made in `main` since that commit onto `Branch B`. Therefore, you are doing the reverse of what you think. It's easier than what you believe, specially if you have some guy to help you visualize the changes. But you should never allow your situation to snowball this far. It's always safer to base your work on `main` and either merge or rebase daily, as to never drift so far.

Comment: Wait I don't want to replay changes from main onto Branch B. I want to replay changes from Branch B onto the latest from main, now that main has the changes from A merged into it.

Answer (score 0):

`git` is handling merges way different than for example `svn` is handling it.

In most cases you can just merge and git will figure it out ;)

You can either:

```
git merge A
git merge B
```

Or go straight for B, since B has also the commits of A in its history.
Git will look for a common ancestor and then merge. So you can just run.

```
git merge B
```

If you haven't created conflicts yourself git will not complain because it knows by the commit IDs that the commits were merged before and that they don't have to be merged again.

This even works with cherry picked commits. If you cherry pick a commit from a branch you can still merge the branch without getting any conflicts.

Comment: Caveat: The commit graph does *not* help to avoid conflicts of cherry-picked commits. Therefore, chances are that they *do* create conflicts. But they do not necessarily do so. Git can frequently avoid conflicts because it can see that both sides of the merge applied the same change. But this discovery is a result of inspecting the actual file content, not of inspecting the commit graph.

Answer (score 0):

To merge branch B into main after branch A has already been merged, you can follow these steps:

**Fetch the Latest Changes:**

```
git fetch origin
```

**Rebase branch B onto main:**
Since you want to include the changes from branch A in both branch A and branch B, rebase branch B onto main:

```
git checkout branch_B
git rebase main
```

This will replay the commits from branch B on top of the latest changes in main.

**Resolve Conflicts (if any):**
If there are conflicts during the rebase, Git will stop and ask you to resolve them. Resolve conflicts in the same way you would during a merge.

```
# After resolving conflicts
git rebase --continue
```

**Push the Changes:**
Once the rebase is complete, push the changes to your GitLab repository:

```
git push origin branch_B
```

**Create a Merge Request for branch B:**
Go to GitLab, create a new merge request for branch B targeting main. Resolve any conflicts that might arise in the GitLab interface.

This approach ensures that you include the changes from branch A in both branch A and branch B. If the changes in branch A have been merged into main as a merge commit, the rebase will incorporate those changes into branch B without creating duplicate commits.

Comment: In the "Rebase branch B onto main" of this answer, why don't we need to modify the `git rebase main` command to exclude the Branch A commits from the replay? In other words when doing that rebase, if line 10 of file X was changed in Branch A, and that change is now in main, won't we be duplicating that commit during the replay?

Comment: No..it wont. Try it out and let me know if that works.